# Using two variables to form a single text file

Tags: shell-script, scripting, python

I am trying to create a text file with below content

```
user name is ${name}
and his mobile number is ${number}
```

I have 10 users and 10 mobile numbers as well. User names are saved in `user.txt` and the contact number is saved in `contact.txt`.

`user.txt` looks like below.

```
apple
cat
tom
```

`contact.txt` looks like below,

```
1234
3456
5678
```

my output should look like below.

```
user name is apple
and his mobile number is 1234

user name is cat
and his mobile number is 3456

user name is tom
and his mobile number is 5678
```

I want this output in single file. Could someone please help me with the shell and python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with standard shell builtins and common tools.

```
paste -d'|' user.txt contact.txt | while IFS='|' read user contact ; do
  printf "user name is %s\nand their mobile is %s\n" "${user}" "${contact}"
done
```

Slight remix with a bashism that is often preferred for input redirection.

```
while IFS='|' read user contact ; do
  printf "user name is %s\nand their mobile is %s\n" "${user}" "${contact}"
done < <(paste -d"|" user.txt contact.txt)
```

The entire output can be redirected to a file of your choice by adding `> "somefilename.txt"` to the last line of either command.

Answer (score 1):

The `paste` command could be used to pair the lines of the two files so that we may read them easier:

```bsh
paste user.txt contact.txt
```

This creates a tab-delimited data stream of two fields.

This is easily read and modified by e.g. `awk`:

```bsh
awk -F '\t' '{ printf "user name is %s\nand his mobile number is %s\n\n", $1, $2 }'
```

This uses `printf` in `awk` to create a string that is outputted.  The two fields read from the output of `paste` are read automatically into `$1` and `$2` and they are inserted into the output string where it says `%s` (a placeholder for the next string given as an argument to `printf`).  The `-F '\t'` on the command line of `awk` sets the field delimiter to a tab character.

Putting these two together and testing it:

```bsh
$ paste user.txt contact.txt | awk -F '\t' '{ printf "user name is %s\nand his mobile number is %s\n\n", $1, $2 }'
user name is apple
and his mobile number is 1234

user name is cat
and his mobile number is 3456

user name is tom
and his mobile number is 5678
```

Redirect this into a file using `>somename` at the end of the command.

---

A different way of doing this is to modify the output field separator (`OFS`) and the output record separator (`ORS`), and instead of using `printf` just modify the first and second field (the trailing `1` at the end causes the output of the modified line):

```bsh
paste user.txt contact.txt |
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\n' -v ORS='\n\n' '{ $1 = "user name is " $1; $2 = "and his mobile number is " $2 }; 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

`bash` has the `mapfile` builtin command, that reads in a file into an array as one element per line. `-t` removes trailing newlines. You may then just loop over the arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t user <user.txt
mapfile -t number <contact.txt
for (( i=0 ; i<${#user[@]} ; i++ )) ; do
  echo "user name is ${user[i]}"
  echo "and his mobile number is ${number[i]}"
  echo
done
```

Comment: Neat ... Could just do this to get `i` values: `for i in ${!user[*]} ; do`

Comment: @bxm That would split the keys on whitespaces though, and do globbing. You probably meant `"${!user[@]}"`. I'm also not sure if ordering is guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: The keys are purely numeric for a "normal" array, so I'm not sure that white space and globbing come into play...?

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
users=( ${(f)"$(<users.txt)"} )
numbers=( ${(f)"$(<numbers.txt)"} )
printf 'user name is %s\nand their mobile is %s\n\n' ${users:^numbers}
```

`${A:^B}` and `${A:^^B}` are two array-zipping operators. The difference between the two can be seen when the two arrays are not of the same length like in `A=(a b c) B=(1 2 3 4 5)` in which case `${A:^B}` yields `a` `1` `b` `2` `c` `3` (discarding the excess from `B`) while `${A:^^B}` yields `a` `1` `b` `2` `c` `3` `a` `4` `b` `5` (reusing `A` members to match against the excess in `B`.